# Use Javascript to clear div before printing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that prints some text when I click a button.

```js
function typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos = 0) {
  if (currentPos < messageToShow.length) {
    document.getElementById(targetElement).innerHTML += messageToShow.charAt(currentPos);
    currentPos++;
    setTimeout(function() { typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos); }, timeBetween);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="typeWriter('TEXT HERE' , 'logone', 20)">Click here</button>

<p id="logone"></p> <br/>
```

Now I have multiple of these, and in order for it to work, I have them print in separate `<p>` elements. So they print in different places. Instead of doing that I'd rather have them print the text in the same element. This means that when you click the button it will erase any text that was already there. How can I do this? Let's say the element to display the text is `<p id="logone">` in my sample code above?

Comment: Create a stylesheet with `media=print` attribute, and add a class to the elements to hide on printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a check to see if `typeWriter` function is being call when the button is clicked for the first time, i.e. `currentPost == 0`. If that's the case then you reset the display element's `innerHTML`. See the following code snippet.

```js
function typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos = 0) {
  var displayEl = document.getElementById(targetElement);
  
  if(currentPos == 0) {
    displayEl.innerHTML = "";
  }
  
  if (currentPos < messageToShow.length) {
    displayEl.innerHTML += messageToShow.charAt(currentPos);
    currentPos++;
    setTimeout(function() { typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos); }, timeBetween);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="typeWriter('TEXT HERE' , 'logone', 20)">Click here</button>

<p id="logone"></p> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another param to check if it should clear the div

```
function typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos = 0, shouldClear) {
    if (currentPos < messageToShow.length) {
        var t = document.getElementById(targetElement);
        if (shouldClear) {
          t.innerHTML = '';
        }
        t.innerHTML += messageToShow.charAt(currentPos);
        currentPos++;
        setTimeout(function() { typeWriter(messageToShow, targetElement, timeBetween, currentPos); }, timeBetween);
    }
}
```

then use it like so

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="typeWriter('TEXT HERE' , 'logone', 20,0,true)">Click here to clear and show this text</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to clear the text. Also for some reason it erases the first letter of whatever it types?

Comment: woops missed a parameter. try it now